# Is it possible for different instances of a generic function to have different static variables?

Tags: rust

When I use a static variable in generic functions, the entities of the variable in each instance of the generic function are all the same.

For instance, in this code

```
fn foo<T>() {
    use std::sync::{Once, ONCE_INIT};

    static INIT: Once = ONCE_INIT;

    INIT.call_once(|| {
        // run initialization here
        println!("Called");
    });
}

fn main() {
    foo::<i64>();
    foo::<i64>();
    foo::<isize>();
}
```

`println!` is called just once.

I had checked the assembly code using the Rust playground and saw that the `INIT` variable is independent of which type `T` actually is although `foo<T>` themselves are instantiated with different name.

Is it possible for different instance of the generic function to have different static variables so that `println!` is called twice in the above example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  Rust doesn't support having static data tied to a generic parameter.

The closest workaround I can think of would be to use something like the [`typemap`](https://crates.io/crates/typemap) crate to store one entry per type.

````
/*!
Add to `Cargo.toml`:

```cargo
[dependencies]
lazy_static = "0.2.8"
typemap = "0.3.3"
```
*/
#[macro_use] extern crate lazy_static;
extern crate typemap;

fn main() {
    foo::<i64>();
    foo::<i64>();
    foo::<isize>();
}

fn foo<T: 'static>() {
    use std::marker::PhantomData;
    use std::sync::Mutex;
    use typemap::{ShareMap, TypeMap};

    // Use `fn(T)` as it avoids having to require that `T` implement
    // `Send + Sync`.
    struct Key<T>(PhantomData<fn(T)>);

    impl<T: 'static> typemap::Key for Key<T> {
        type Value = ();
    }

    lazy_static! {
        static ref INIT: Mutex<ShareMap> = Mutex::new(TypeMap::custom());
    }

    INIT.lock().unwrap().entry::<Key<T>>().or_insert_with(|| {
        println!("Called");
    });
}
````

Comment: Although this may not be a good question, do you know why rust does not support static variable with a generic parameter?

Comment: @hfukuda: Not really.  Probably because no one ever needed it badly enough.