# Cannot return a static reference to a temporary array even when the array contains a value that also has the static lifetime

Tags: rust

The value returned from `T::bar` has the `'static` lifetime, so `Test2::foo` scope doesn't need to own anything. Returning `&[T::bar()]` as `&'static [&'static StructType]` should be safe? `Test:foo` compiles without issue so I was expecting `Test2::foo` to compile as well.

Code

```
pub struct StructType {
    a: &'static str,
}

pub trait Foo {
    fn foo() -> &'static [&'static StructType];
    fn bar() -> &'static StructType;
}

pub struct Test;

impl Foo for Test {
    fn foo() -> &'static [&'static StructType] {
        &[&StructType { a: "asdf" }]
    }

    fn bar() -> &'static StructType {
        &StructType { a: "asdf" }
    }
}

pub struct Test2<T: Foo>(T);

impl<T: Foo> Test2<T> {
    pub fn foo() -> &'static [&'static StructType] {
        &[T::bar()]
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8302df38385b63a75d18ad9d5baca4f6)

Error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return reference to temporary value
  --> src/lib.rs:26:9
   |
26 |         &[T::bar()]
   |         ^----------
   |         ||
   |         |temporary value created here
   |         returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

Comment: never mind, it's because `T::bar()` is not a constant function so, array is not constant, so the array is construct at runtime. Maybe you can work around with the nightly feature of const function. Doesn't look like trait can have const function, https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24111

Comment: @Stargateur I see your point. The array of `Test::foo` only contains constants so it is possible to take a static lifetime reference from it. But for `Test2:foo` it have to evaluate some non-const expression which make the array non const and therefore cannot be taken static lifetime reference from it. Is this right?

Comment: that what I think yes, maybe wait some other opinion because I'm not a rust expert yet ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the return value's lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49581900/how-do-i-set-the-return-values-lifetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RFC that added the automatic promotion of references to values to `'static`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1414-rvalue_static_promotion.md) states:

> Promote constexpr rvalues to values in static memory instead of stack slots, and expose those in the language by being able to directly create 'static references to them.

Literal values are the most obvious constant expressions. However, a function call is *not* constant unless explicitly marked as such using `const`. However, as of Rust 1.31, the types of operations that are available in a user-defined `const` function are fairly limited. Literal values are allowed:

```
const fn bar() -> &'static StructType {
    &StructType("asdf")
}

const fn combo() -> &'static [&'static StructType; 1] {
    &[Self::bar()]
}
```

Converting from a reference to an array to a slice is *not* allowed in a `const` function yet, so that needs to be in a different function:

```
fn wombo() -> &'static [&'static StructType] {
    Self::combo()
}
```

Additionally, you cannot define `const` functions in a trait.

See also:

- [Why can I return a reference to a local literal but not a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50345139/155423)
- [Why is it legal to borrow a temporary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47662253/155423)
- ["Expected type parameter" error in the constructor of a generic struct](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551177/155423)

> What I really need are 1) have `T::bar()` return a constant, 2) have `Test:foo` return an array constant, that is constructed from `T::bar()` and `U::bar()` and `U`, `T` are generic parameter to `Test`

You cannot do this

```
fn example<T>() {
    static NO_CAN_DO: T = unimplemented!();
}
```

```
error[E0401]: can't use type parameters from outer function
 --> src/lib.rs:2:23
  |
1 | fn example<T>() {
  |    ------- - type variable from outer function
  |    |
  |    try adding a local type parameter in this method instead
2 |     static NO_CAN_DO: T = unimplemented!();
  |                       ^ use of type variable from outer function
```

See also:

- [Is it possible for different instances of a generic function to have different static variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45892973/155423)
- [What is the rationale for not being able to use the outer type parameter within an inner function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47967549/155423)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking about lifetimes the wrong way. It seems like you use them to "declare" how long you want it to live, but you can't change the lifetime of a reference. All the lifetime specifiers do is to help the compiler to understand the lifetime in cases where it doesn't have the information to elide it.

[Chapter 15.4.7 Static from Rust by Example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/static_lifetime.html) should help you out.

Basically, there are only two ways you can create `'static` data:

1. Make a constant with the `static` declaration.
2. Make a string literal which has type: `&'static str`.

You could achieve the same as above by declaring lifetimes specifiers like you normally do in Rust (but the compiler suggested a `'static` lifetime since you hadn't declared any lifetimes yourself). See below.

The main point is that, with the exception of `&'static str`, a lifetime can never be changed by annotating lifetimes in your functions. When you write `&[T::bar()]`, the array is not a constant and will get dropped when you leave the scope if your function. If you want it to live with a `'static` lifetime, you need to make it a constant like I show below.

Now that's probably not exactly what you wanted to do but it will compile and I hope explain the difference:

```
const ARR: &'static [&'static StructType] = &[&StructType { a: "asdf" }];

pub struct StructType {
    a: &'static str,
}

pub trait Foo<'a> {
    fn foo() -> &'a [&'a StructType];
    fn bar() -> &'a StructType;
}

pub struct Test;

impl<'a> Foo<'a> for Test {
    fn foo() -> &'a [&'a StructType] {
        &[&StructType { a: "asdf" }]
    }

    fn bar() -> &'a StructType {
        &StructType { a: "asdf" }
    }
}

pub struct Test2<T: Foo<'static>>(T);

impl<T: Foo<'static>> Test2<T> {
    pub fn foo() -> &'static [&'static StructType] {
        ARR
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But unfortunately your example doesn't help much. I know how to make something compiles. But I want to know if it is possible for the current Rust compiler to support my use cases. (i.e. return static reference of an array that contains a result from some method call)

Comment: Also I don't see why make a generic lifetime parameter helps at all. All I needs to support is `'static`.

Comment: Const functions is soon landing in rust, but I don't think that will make a difference here (if I understand your question correctly). The problem is that the array you create only lives to the end of that function (that memory is freed at that point), even if the array contains static data. So you need to make a static array, and that has to be a constant. The generic lifetimes doesn't help, but in this case declaring them as static don't make any sense either so it was just to seperate the 'statics that served a purpose from those that just as well could be a generic parameter.

Comment: @BryanChen [one solution](https://play.integer32.com/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8f51d333a06969bbad224e7d9f1ed1d) could be this at the moment but as you didn't provide why you want this it's hard to me to guess what you need.

Comment: Maybe it's me misunderstanding the question, and if so I'm sorry, but the method call you want to have as static needs to be known at compile time (which it is here since you only store static strings) but you will still need to declare it as a const... If you look here at const functions, maybe that's what you're looking for (still have to be a constant though): https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/reference/blob/3a7b6d863183079d46d92313df7875e22801de8d/src/items/functions.md#const-functions

Comment: What I really need are 1) have `T::bar()` return a constant, 2) have `Test:foo` return an array constant, that is constructed from `T::bar()` and `U::bar()` and `U`, `T` are generic parameter to `Test`. I have tried static variable solution and it doesn't work with generic type

Comment: I haven't tried it for your case but if that's not working either I don't think your exact problem is so easy to solve the way you want it to right now without changing the design somewhat. Maybe someone else has a solution that I haven't thought of.

Comment: I can't figure out how to make `lazy_static` works with generic. I don't just have one static variable, I will like to have one per type implements `Foo` trait.

Comment: If I can't make this work, I can always adjust the design to workaround it. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: [Your basic premise about ways to create static data is incorrect](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=50f5ed4ff8c83bb041ab6fe0e0a86400)

Comment: @Shepmaster. Thanks for feedback, but can you elaborate where the premise is wrong? My main point was that a lifetime for a non-str type doesn't change if you declare them as 'static. It has no meaning other than telling the compiler you intend for it to live the full lifetime of the program, but the compiler will still stop you if you don't actually live up to your intentions and declare the variable as a const or static variable...

Comment: I changed the example to not use primitives and add a scope where a "static" lifetime should outlive the scope: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a3576b29d4f4c4846cf6216c224a081d